# Conditional replacement based on sub-strings and dictionaries?

Tags: python

I am working with a dataset that includes restaurant orders as in the example below (i.e. all order components are aggregated as a single string separated by "-")

```
orders_all = ['soup-steak-cake-riesling', 'salad-chardonnay-fish', 'syrah-salad-steak-cake']
```

I would like to extract the different items into independent lists in order to facilitate the data analyses but I am struggling to find the right function/s. Ideally, given a dictionary as the one below, the script would be able to go through the order components and return the respective wine type as per the dictionary.

```
wine_dict = {'riesling': 'white', 'chardonnay': 'white', 'syrah': 'red'}

orders_wine = ['white', 'white', 'red']
```

Any recommendations? :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you encountering? Maybe give us some code that you wrote so that we know at what point you are in writing a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do this more manually than i would prefer based on the types of ordered items assuming you want to to do this for more than just wine. But the below should get you what you want.

```
orders_wine = []

for order in orders_all:
    temp_list = order.split('-')
    for item in temp_list:
        if item in wine_dict:
            orders_wine.append(wine_dict[item])
```

This will give you a list `orders_wine` that will be along the lines of `['white', 'white', 'red']`

However, I'd recommend doing something like:

```
wine_type_orders = {'white':0, 'red':0}

for order in orders_all:
    temp_list = order.split('-')
    for item in temp_list:
        if item in wine_dict:
            wine_type_orders[wine_dict[item]] +=1
            #wine_dict[item] would give red or white which are the keys for wine_type_orders and +=1 would increment the counter
```